Finding $\displaystyle \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{f(n)}$ where $f(x)$ is infinite nested radical

If


$\displaystyle f(x)=x\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+(x+3)}}}\cdots \cdots $. Then $\displaystyle \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{f(n)}=$

What I try :Replace $x\rightarrow  (x+1)$ in original equation , we get
$\displaystyle f(x+1)=(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+(x+3)\sqrt{1\cdots }}}$
$\displaystyle x\sqrt{f(x+1)+1}=x\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1\cdots }}}$
We get $\displaystyle x \sqrt{f(x+1)+1}=f(x)$
$\displaystyle x^2\bigg(f(x+1)+1\bigg)=f^2(x)$
Now I did not ununderstand How can I solve after that , please have a look on that , Thanks

Try showing that $f(x) = x(x + 2)$ by using $x + a = \sqrt {1 + (x + a - 1)(x + a + 1)} $.

Thanks Gray , But How can I extend into infinite series. please explain me.

We have
$$\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+(x+3)\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}=x+2$$
(A proof is written at the end of this answer)
So, we have $f(x)=x(x+2)$ and so
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(n)}&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac 12\bigg(\frac 1n-\frac{1}{n+2}\bigg)
\\\\&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac 12\bigg(\frac 11+\frac 12-\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}\bigg)
\\\\&=\color{red}{\frac 34}\end{align}$$

In the following, I'm going to prove that
$$\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+(x+3)\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}=x+2$$
for $x\ge -1$.
We want to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(x)=x+2$ where $$p_1(x)=\sqrt{x+2},p_{n+1}(x)=\sqrt{1+(x+1)p_{n}(x+1)}$$
We have
$$p_2(x)=\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{x+3}}$$
$$p_{3}(x)=\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{x+4}}}$$
$$p_{4}(x)=\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+(x+3)\sqrt{x+5}}}}$$
It is sufficient to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}q_n(x)=0$ where $q_n(x)=x+2-p_n(x)$.
$(1)$ $q_n(x)$ is decreasing in $n$.Proof : Since $p_n(x)$ is increasing in $n$, we see that $q_n(x)=x+2-p_n(x)$ is decreasing in $n$.$\ \square$
$(2)$ $0\le q_n(x)$.Proof : Let us prove by induction on $n$ that $p_n(x)\le x+2$. We have $x+2-p_1(x)=\frac{(x+1)\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+2}+1}\ge 0$. Suppose that $p_n(x)\le x+2$. Then, we have $$x+2-p_{n+1}(x)=\frac{(x+2)^2-(1+(x+1)p_n(x+1))}{x+2+p_{n+1}(x)}=\frac{(x+1)(x+3-p_n(x+1))}{x+2+p_{n+1}(x+1)}\ge 0.\ \square$$
$(3)$ $q_n(x)\le \frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{x+n+1}$.Proof : We have $$\begin{align}q_{n+1}(x)&=x+2-p_{n+1}(x)
\\\\&=\frac{(x+1)(x+3-p_n(x+1))}{x+2+p_{n+1}(x+1)}
\\\\&=\frac{(x+1)q_{n}(x+1)}{x+2+p_{n+1}(x)}
\\\\&\color{red}{\le}\frac{x+1}{x+3}q_n(x+1)\end{align}$$ where $p_{n+1}(x)\ge 1$ was used in the inequality in red. So, we have
$$\begin{align}q_{n}(x)&\le\frac{x+1}{x+3}q_{n-1}(x+1)
\\\\&\le \frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{(x+3)(x+4)}q_{n-2}(x+2)
\\\\&\le \frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{(x+4)(x+5)}q_{n-3}(x+3)
\\\\&\quad\quad\vdots
\\\\&\le \frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{(x+n)(x+n+1)}q_{1}(x+n-1)
\\\\&\color{red}{\le} \frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{x+n+1}\end{align}$$
where $q_{1}(x+n-1)\le x+n$ (which is equivalent to $p_1(x+n-1)\ge 1$) was used in the inequality in red.$\ \square$
Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$$\frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{x+n+1}=0$, we finally get $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n(x)=0$.$\ \blacksquare$

Claim: $f(x) = x(x+2)$, for $x \in \Bbb N$. 
Proof: $f(1) = 3$ is the famous infinite nested radical of Ramanujan. We proceed by induction. Assume the claim is true for $x=k$. You have already derived
$$k^2(f(k+1)+1) = f(k)^2$$
which gives
$$f(x+1) + 1 = (x+2)^2 \iff f(x+1) = (x+1)(x+3)$$as desired. $\blacksquare$
Now, you can easily telescope to get the answer as $\boxed{3/4}$.

To show the result for positive reals, we can do the following:
Claim: $f(x) = x(x+2)  \ \ \forall x \ge 0$. 
Proof: Define $f_n(x)$ as
$$f_n(x) = x\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+\ldots (x+n)\sqrt{1+(x+n+1)(x+n+3)}}}$$
We show $f_n(x) = x(x+2)$ $\forall n \in \Bbb N$ and $x\ge0$.
Note that $1+k(k+2) = (k+1)^2 \implies f_n(x) = f_{n-1}(x)$ and hence working backwards we have $f_n(x) = x(x+2)$. 
We observe that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$, as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x+n)^{1/2^n} = 1$.
Hence $f(x) = x(x+2)$. $\blacksquare$
